# Is there a way in Angular to create a duplicate row in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a method where I iterate through an array, using ng-repeat and pair each item with a value from a dropdown list.

Here is a jsfiddle of that method:

https://jsfiddle.net/4zbvv5gq/4/

```
<header>
    <title>myTittle</title>
</header>
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div>
            <form>
                <table class="table  table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <th>From File</th>
                        <th>Map To</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tr class="selector-row" ng-repeat="(key,value) in List1">
                        <td><span id="myspan">{{value}}</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="padding:10px;">
                            <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data[value]" class="form-control">
                                <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in Match" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>{{ data }}</div>
    </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.List1 = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5'];
    $scope.Match = ['match1', 'match2', 'match3', 'match4', 'match5'];
}])
```

My challenge is I want to be able to let a user click on something like an "add" link in any of the rows and 1)create a duplicate of that row, then 2) select a different value from the select list.

Comment: It would be fairly easy to use a controller to do what you describe. Your question is to broad, however, as you apparently haven't made an attempt. Please do so and return with a more specific question.

Comment: Hi Isherwood, I actually thought my question was fairly specific. I was looking for input on an approach and was hoping for some helpful direction. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a "Add Row" button at the end and push a new value to your `List1` like this in your controller. See an update to your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4zbvv5gq/7/) here.

```
$scope.addRow = function(){
    var len = $scope.List1.length;
    $scope.List1.push('product'+(len+1));
}
```

And right after your table, add a button that calls the above function:

```
   </table>
   <button ng-click="addRow()">Add a row</button>
```

Comment: This adds a new (empty) row, but I don't think it duplicates a specific row as the OP requests.

Comment: @isherwood, it does duplicate a row because the values are already nested in the row, and inside the `ng-repeat` of the row items. If you add a new value to the row, the entire content of the row will be added, thus duplicating the entire row. I would like to hear from the OP if the answer deviates from his/her requirements.

Comment: How does your single button know which row to duplicate?

Comment: It really doesn't matter, the data to be selected for the duplicate row comes from another variable that needs to be independently selected to get a new value, as the OP suggests: "2) select a different value from the select list". In fact, it is just an additional row, and not necessarily a "duplicate". And to do what is asked, you don't need to "duplicate" a specific row.

Comment: Hi Guys, this is indeed what I'm looking for with the exception that isherwood is right. I'm trying to duplicate a specific row. For instance clicking an add button net to "product 2" and creating another "product 2" row. So the result would look like ['product1': 'match4', 'product2':'match1','product2':'match5']. So I do need to target a specific row and duplicate that value. Thanks for the help. You've already given me some good direction!

Comment: Sure. But what you are trying to do is have an object with duplicate keys, which is not right. Somehow you will have to create unique keys to associate the "duplicate" rows. Here's how I would do it, without having to change a lot of your data representation. See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4zbvv5gq/8/.

Comment: show-me-the-code, Your suggestion worked well. I just needed to add track by index. However, my problem now is adding unique values to the duplicate columns. See what I did to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4zbvv5gq/9/

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work because you are trying to add different values to the same key in a single object. That is why I suggested using different keys by doing something like this: `product1(0), product1(1)` in my example. If that is not going to work for you, you should be looking at changing how you represent your data entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Dublicate row in angular is possible.I give an sample code for dublicate row

index.html part:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div style="padding: 10px;">
    <h2>Languages</h2>
    <br/>
    <div style="width: 90%; display: inline-block; border: 1px silver dotted;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <select class="form-control" ng-init="nativeLanguage.level = 'Native'" data-ng-model="nativeLanguage.level" tooltip="Level">
            <option value="Native" ng-selected="true">Native</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="nativeLanguage.name" tooltip="Language">
            <option value="">Language</option>
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="IT">Italian</option>
            <option value="DE">German</option>
            <option value="FR">French</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <input type="text" data-ng-model="nativeLanguage.remark" class="form-control" placeholder="Remark" tooltip="Remark">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div select-last ng-repeat='language in languages'></div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn" style="margin-bottom: 27px;" href="#" tooltip="Add" ng-click='addRow()'>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    </a>
    <pre>{{nativeLanguage | json}}</pre>
    <pre>{{languages | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

ap.js part:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('selectLast', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'language.html',
        /*scope: {
          level: '=',
          name: '=',
          remark: '='
        },*/
        replace: true
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.languages = [];
    /*var nativeLanguage = {
        level: $scope.hr.language.level,
        name: $scope.hr.language.name,
        remark: $scope.hr.language.remark
    };*/
    $scope.languages.push($scope.nativeLanguage);

    $scope.addRow = function(){
        var newLanguage = {
          level: $scope.level,
          name: $scope.name,
          remark: $scope.remark
        };
        $scope.languages.push(newLanguage);
        console.log('+ clicked');
    };

    $scope.deleteRow = function(rowNo) {
        /*$scope.items.splice($scope.newitem);*/
        $scope.languages.splice(rowNo, 1);
        console.log('- clicked in row ' + rowNo);
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yasemin. This helps.